# How to subscribe to PropertyChange event with Fody-propertychanged

Tags: fody-propertychanged

Create winform project targeting .net 4.5.1

Install-Package PropertyChanged.Fody

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class PersonFody
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

PersonFody _fod = new PersonFody();

_fod. //Name is the only property and no events to subscribe

Is it possible to subscribe to a PropertyChanged event at design time using fody?
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess this is late, but yes you can. Just add this event to your class:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Fody will recognize you have the correct event for the IPropertyChanged interface and wire all your properties to trigger that event.